# How to add only single value from Autocomplete in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have an Autocomplete component for adding country calling code, but, the relevant country is added too with it. Like when clicked on Autocomplete drop-down list, all the countries and its specific codes are displayed. My intention is to add only the country code. See the code below for reference

```
const [countryData, setCountryData] = useState({});
const [newValue, setNewValue] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
    setCountryData(codes);
}, []);


<Autocomplete
        id="size-small-standard"
        size="small"
        options={cities}
        onChange={(event, value) => setNewValue(value)}
        autoSelect={true}
        getOptionLabel={(option) =>
          option.country + " " + ` +` + option.calling_code {/* <-- How to display only calling code, but, should show both country name and calling code in drop down  */}
        }
        defaultValue={cities[98]} 
        style={{ width: "100%" }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            variant="standard"
            placeholder="Search your country"
            style={{ width: "40%" }}
          />
        )}
      />
```

What would be best possible solution?

Following is the CodeSandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-3ljj2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your `getOptionLabel` to show only the phone prefix and then use `renderOption` to show the name with the country's phone prefix

```js
return (
  <div className={classes.root}>
    <Autocomplete
      id="size-small-standard"
      size="small"
      options={cities}
      onChange={(event, value) => setNewValue(value)}
      autoSelect={true}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => `+ ${option.calling_code}`}
      renderOption={(option) => (
        <>{`${option.country} + ${option.calling_code}`}</>
      )}
      defaultValue={cities[98]}
      style={{ width: "100%" }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          variant="standard"
          placeholder="Search your country"
          style={{ width: "40%" }}
        />
      )}
    />
  </div>
);
```

#### Live Demo

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

## UPDATE:

Here is a better example, where you can still search for the country.

#### Live Demo

[image: Edit how-to-add-only-single-value-from-autocomplete-in-material-ui]